# How to recognize textfiled data type java string or integer

Tags: java, netbeans, awt

I have text box and i want to know data type entered by user into the text box
and depend on type i want to do something 
if there any functions to know data type it will be great .

Comment: you can use try catch or regex to find appropriate datatype

Comment: You use a JFormattedTextField or JSpinner or even a DocumentFilter depending on your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;    
StringUtils.isNumeric(String s);
```

Notice this doesn't throw exceptions on regular cases, which should be avoided in every possible scenario.

Comment: Thank you Attila and great but seems  ineed your help the library not listing in my netbeans as follows

Comment: am using java netbeans IDE 8 , but the import not showing below
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;  
instead they are showing only
import  org.apache.derby 
how i can add jar or import to gain the whole import into my netbeans so as to use the "StringUtils" function

Comment: yes now working great i attached new jar org-apache-commons-lang.jar  and the function now working fine thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
String name= scanner.nextLine();
try{
   int integerValue = Integer.parseInt(name);
   sysout("Name is integer value")
}
catch(NumberFormatException){
  sysout("name is not an integer value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default you will get string type only, you have to write your own logic for checking datatype. 
you can restrict input for numberic or string values only using javascript.